# How to migrate magento 1 to magento 2 programmatically in localhost using PHP ?? Is any anyone have idea related this topic

Tags: magento2

Actually I am trying to migrate Magento 1 to Magento 2 in localhost. Do any one have idea related this topic ?

Below code not useful.

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Mage_Tempjs',
    __DIR__
);


<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Mage_Tempjs" setup_version="2.0.2" active="true">

    </module>
</config>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should refer official guide for this, as your question is quite wast in scope.

[Data Migration Tool](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/migration/migration-tool-install.html), [Migration overview](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/migration/bk-migration-guide.html) , [data-migration-tool](https://github.com/magento/data-migration-tool)